# Elastic Search doesn't give me any error when updating non existent document

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm running an `updateByQuery` operation in ElasticSearch using Spring Data ElasticSearch (Spring Boot parent v2.6.1, Elastic Search 7.15.2).

In my ES index I have stored 2 documents.

When I give a non-existent document in the search, it doesn't give me any error, because of which I'm not able to distinguish whether the update actually ran or not.

Updates for a document that exists work fine. I'd like to figure a way such that if no rows are edited, I can log it.

What should I look at? What should I change so that I can get some message to understand if there was an update?

Here's my code snippet:

```
UpdateByQueryRequest request = new UpdateByQueryRequest('index');
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("marks", "30");
    data.put("name", "timmy");
    data.put("roll_number", "10");
    request.setScript(
            new Script(
                ScriptType.INLINE, "painless",
                "if (ctx._source.name == params.name && ctx._source.roll_number == params.roll_number) {ctx._source.marks=params.marks;}",
                data));
    BulkByScrollResponse resp = globalClient.updateByQuery(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    log.info("response: {}",resp.getStatus());
```

I've added the response status as well. What I find weird is that in case of both existent and non-existent document, the `updated` parameter count is `2`, same as the number of documents I have in my index.

response in case of non-existent record:

```
response: BulkIndexByScrollResponse[sliceId=null,updated=2,created=0,deleted=0,batches=1,versionConflicts=0,noops=0,retries=0,throttledUntil=0s]
```

response in case of existing record:

```
response: BulkIndexByScrollResponse[sliceId=null,updated=2,created=0,deleted=0,batches=1,versionConflicts=0,noops=0,retries=0,throttledUntil=0s]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pure Elasticsearch code, nothing from Spring Data Elasticsearch .

Where do you specify the query? I don't see any in your code. That means that all documents will be updated - 2 in your case.

Comment: I'm following the Script example in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-update-by-query.html where a script is passed to modify a document based on condition

Comment: on that page: "You can limit the documents by adding a query." You do not set a query, that's why all documents get updated.

Comment: got it.. I was under the impression that this script would be acting as query and update as well